# Inkscape: Snap shape center to stroke

Tags: inkscape, snapping

I have an unfilled circle on which I want to draw smaller filled circles. I want to make sure that the center of the small circles is snapped to the stroke of the largest one, to ensure harmonious distribution of the shapes.

[image]

However, even enabling "Snap to objects", I'm not sure that's what I get. There doesn't seem to be a center handle to snap on the stroke.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Snap Controls Bar select the following options:

- Enable snapping
- Snap nodes paths and handles
- Snap to paths
- Snap other points
- Snap centres of objects

Here's the result

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was missing some of the snapping options, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use polar arrangement:

- Create as many small circles as you need
- Create a circle, arc or ellipse on which to arrange the circles, keep it selected
- Shift+click to select the small circles
- Object > Arrange (the last item)
- second tab 'Polar coordinates'
- Arrange

[image: Before]

[image: After]